# Error in is.data.frame(data) : object '.' not found in anovaPE function

Tags: r, linear-regression, envstats

I'm trying to do lack of fit analisys for a college activity, however when I use anovaPE() to try to get the full ANOVA table, i get the following error:

Error in is.data.frame(data) : object '.' not found

I'm using this dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Skls9xI0ljzEokgdEs9ayuiSut5ykoXG/view

It's a really simple dataset with a few observations about HandSpan and heigths, to make a linear model with x = handspan, y = height.

I'm using the following packages:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(car)
library(EnvStats)
```

code for the model:

```
modelo = dados %>% lm(formula = Height~HandSpan, method = 'lm')
summary(modelo)
```

everything works just fine untill I try to use the anovaPE function from the EnvStats package:

```
anovaPE(modelo)
```

where I get the already mentioned error message:

```
Error in is.data.frame(data) : object '.' not found
```

I've checked the class of modelo, it's an 'lm' as required by the function.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `lm()` is `formula` not `data`, so using the pipe operator in this way results in an error later on. Try using the `data` argument instead. Note that adding `method = 'lm'` to `lm()` results in an error for me so I've omitted it here.

```r
library(car)
library(EnvStats)

modelo = lm(formula = disp~hp, data = mtcars)
summary(modelo)
anovaPE(modelo)
```